# How do I send a token to headers?

Tags: reactjs, axios

How do I send a token to headers?

[image]

My code:

```
  getCategoryList = () => {
    return axios.get(`${this._api}/groups/list`, {
      headers: {"X-CSRF-TOKEN": `Bearer ${this._token}`},
    });
  };
```

Comment: your problem is related to cors not enabled on the server or let me say the backend, not a token issue.

Answer (score 0):

Is this from your back-end? If yes, try to install cors module with `npm install cors` if you use Node.js and use this code

```
const express = require("express");
const cors = require("cors");
const app = express();
app.use(cors());
```

or if you use deno, you can try this

```
import { oakCors } from "https://deno.land/x/cors/mod.ts";
import { Application } from "https://deno.land/x/oak/mod.ts";
const app = new Application();
app.use(oakCors());
```